# How can I avoid duplicate content with TYPO3 v9 when having a news entry with multiple categories

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, tx-news

I am working on a TYPO3 v10 LTS website with integration of the news extension v8.3.0. Many news are assigned to multiple categories and they are displayed on different detail pages according to their assigned categories. Now I would like to define one categories as master and use this category for the generation of canonical links to avoid duplicate content problems. On an older version of the website (TYPO3 v7 LTS) I used the solution explained here: https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/116056/

I'm not so experienced with TYPO3 v9/v10 LTS yet, but I think that there must be a solution with routeEnhancers.

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need no route enhancer, just use the basic configuration of `EXT:news`.

one solution would be: for detail-view (`show`) always use one page. in this way each news will have a unique url. (problem: you can't ´return´ to the former list view with a hard link[1], as you don't know from which list you came)

2nd: configure a show-page with your news-categories: this page will be preferred for detail view (it always will be the first category) and each news will always be shown on this category detail page. (no ´return´ to the original list as above)

[1] you can't use a page as link target, but you can use `javascript:history.back()`